# How can I return my old style project file back?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csproj

Microsoft.NET.Sdk is nice but for old WinForms applications that are targeting .net framework it works really bad.

There are lots of annoying things like exception in Designer, no build-in support for adding new UserControl and Forms and so on.

I know there are tools to convert project to new sdk and I've done that but now I see it was a hasty decision.

I wasn't able to find anything that helps me return back my old style project file.

The one option is manual converting and I really don't want to do that. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you have Source control integration for your project, like Git, Azure DevOps, etc.?
If yes you can simply use it to check the project earlier version.

Comment: So I suppose your project is not in sourcecontrol and you haven't done this migration in a separate branch ?  Think it's a good lesson to start using source-control :)

Comment: Of course I use git))

Comment: I haven't seen much issues until now because the changes didn't required adding new UserControls and Forms.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be a good lesson to always use git even when doing simple experiments. Btw using Visual Studio you can do that rarely easily.

Comment: I do use git always.

Comment: Sorry the last comment was added even though I didn't write it totally. Let me explain. I converted the project to new sdk after I thought I've created all forms and usercontrols. It works okay and I did massive restructurization. But now I have to add features to the project and the more I fight with poor VS support for WinForms project the more I understand I have to go back to old project system. Okay, as far I understand there is no automatic solution and I have to convert it manually.

Comment: anyway thank you both for comments